# Does python yield imply continue?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have a for loop that checks a series of conditions.  On each iteration, it should yield output for only one of the conditions.  The final yield is a default, in case none of the conditions are true.  Do I have to put a *continue* after each block of yields?

```
def function():
    for ii in aa:
       if condition1(ii):
           yield something1
           yield something2
           yield something3
           continue

       if condition2(ii):
           yield something4
           continue

       #default
       yield something5
       continue
```

Answer (score 27):

NO, yield doesn't imply continue, it just starts at next line, next time. A simple example demonstrates that

```
def f():
    for i in range(3):
        yield i
        print i,

list(f())
```

This prints 0,1,2 but if yield continues, it won't

Answer (score 17):

Instead of using the `continue` statement I would suggest using the `elif` and `else` statments:

```
def function():
    for ii in aa:
       if condition1(ii):
           yield something1
           yield something2
           yield something3

       elif condition2(ii):
           yield something4

       else: #default
           yield something5
```

This seems much more readable to me

Answer (score 16):

`yield` in Python stops execution and returns the value. When the iterator is invoked again it continues execution directly after the `yield` statement. For instance, a generator defined as:

```
def function():
    yield 1
    yield 2
```

would return `1` then `2` sequentially. In other words, the `continue` is required. However, in this instance, `elif` and `else` as flashk described are definitely the right tools.

Answer (score 4):

`continue` skips the remaining code block, but the code block after `yield` is executed when `next()` is called again on the generator. `yield` acts like pausing execution at certain point.

Answer (score 2):

This way is more clear, hope it helps, also thanks Anurag Uniyal.

```
def f():
    for i in range(3):
        yield i
        print(i+10)

list(f())
```

----------- after run ------------

```
10
11
12
[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: great, but i think for the list output also a print is needed: print(list(f()))

Comment: Shouldn't this type of comment be on reddit :)?

Answer (score 0):

If the something is simple value and conditions are checks for equality, I would prefer to make this "case structure" dictionary lookup:

```
ii_dict={'a':('somethinga1','somethinga2','somethinga3'),'b':('somethingb1',)}
ii_default = ('somethingdefault',)
aa='abeabbacd'

def function():
    return (value
           for ii in aa
           for value in (ii_dict[ii] if ii in ii_dict else ii_default))

for something in function(): print something
```